# How do I return a token from net core api controller to React

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, jwt

I have a controller that the user will be redirected to after authenticating with OAuth from a 3rd party service. This is a simplified version of the controller:

```
    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Test(string code, string scope, string state = null)
    {
        // Get additional Authorization tokens etc from 3rd party here
        var token = "MyGeneratedJwtToken";
        return new RedirectResult("/dashboard");
    }
```

I could pass the token as a parameter in the URL but that seems like a really bad idea. I'm not quite sure how I would return the data to the React UI and also navigate to a specific react route (/dashboard) at the same time.

I can not hit the endpoint using fetch as the user will be redirected to this controller from a third party.

Edit:
To make it more clear the flow looks like this:
User visits my websites and clicks login which then redirects the user to a third party oauth website where they press authorize. The 3rd party website then redirects back to my controller that I pasted above. In the controller a post request will be made back to the 3rd party oauth flow to get an access and refresh token etc. I then create a jwt token represented by the variable in the code above which I want to send back to the react client.

Comment: I think you should do redirection on React.

Comment: The client browser is responsible for putting an values like headers, cookies, POST bodies, etc. So if you want to make the user pass a token to an external URL, your best option is with the query string parameter. This should be supported on most all browsers without needed new features that only some may support.

Comment: @MustafaArslan is correct. Your API should return a value that your React application receives in response to an AJAX request. Then your react application is free to redirect if it so desires. This approach is idiomatic and has numerous design advantages.